# How to set permanent mtu size for ppp0

Tags: vpn, ubuntu-14.04, mtu

Every time I connect to my VPN, I should run

```
sudo ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1300
```

How could I make it permanent?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as farshad said in following link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196425/how-to-set-permanent-mtu-size-for-ppp0/32196605#32196605

the answer is add new file inside /etc/network/if-up.d/:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" = "ppp0" ]; then
    sudo ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1300
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

I've tried to apply Farshad's solution on ubuntu 16, and it wasn't working.

Only small fix was needed there - remove `sudo` inside your script, because everything inside `/etc/network/if-up.d/` dir is already run as root user

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" = "ppp0" ]; then
    ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1300
fi
```

Comment: don't forget to ```chmod +x file_created```

Answer (score 3):

As I said at this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196425/how-to-set-permanent-mtu-size-for-ppp0/32196605#32196605)

You can make your custom script

at this address :  `/etc/network/if-up.d`,

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$IFACE" = "ppp0" ]; then
    sudo ifconfig ppp0 mtu 1300
fi
```

finally make executable and enjoy from your life ...

Answer (score 2):

You can define the `mtu` setting inside the `/etc/ppp/options` file. The setting should already be present in the `options` file but should be commented out by default.

Comment: It's not working, I diconnect and connect again but still shows 1400 mtu size

Comment: @MohseTaheri: You will have to look into the PPTP config file (`/etc/pptpd.conf`) to see what file is defined for the `option` setting. By default, PPP looks in `/etc/ppp/options` but on Debian systems I have seen that the setting is overwritten to look into `/etc/ppp/pptpd-options`. You may have to make changes accordingly.

Comment: it read `/etc/ppp/options` because when I set wrong mtu size it shows me an error but after setting correct value it doesn't change the mtu size after connection

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 22.04, been looking for this solution for a while